# Script crashes if type wrong or nothing

Tags: python

This is a simple menu.If i type a wrong number or nothing script crashes.

```
print "1) menu 1"
print "2) menu 2"
print "q) quit"

choice = raw_input("?> ")

while choice is not 'q' or 'Q':
```

script is looping the print message from here

```
    if choice == '1':   
        print "menu1"
```

same loop here

```
    elif choice == '2':
        print "menu2"  

    else:
        print "invalid choice"
        # want to start the input question again from here

print "breaked out of the loop"
```

Comment: Define "crashes". What happens? Is there an error message? What is it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This is an example. There seems to be no GOTO function like in c++.If i type 3 or hit enter script is ending.but i want the input question again

Comment: @FillethackerRanjid What is the error, and why do you want GOTO? Also, you just edited the question to use `raw_input()`. Did that not fix the problem?

Comment: raw_input didn't fixed the problem

Comment: @FillethackerRanjid So what error are you getting?

Comment: `GOTO` is one of the worst control structures known to man.

Comment: @2rs2ts: Yes, `COMEFROM` is much more interesting, especially [with threading](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~malcolmr/intercal/threaded.html). But I'm more interested in the fact that he wants `GOTO` as a _function_, than that he wants it in the first place. I'm struggling to understand what that could mean, but I suspect once I figure it out it will lead to a breakthrough as important as continuation-passing…

Comment: @abarnert I'm crying, you linked me to INTERCAL... My second favorite name for a programming language after TMMLPTEALPAITAFNFAL.

Comment: @2rs2ts: Well, INTERCAL is certainly harder to sing about (given that by definition it has no pronunciation) than TMMLPTEALPAITAFNFAL, but I'm not sure that actually makes it a better name, because not everyone has a singing voice as bad as mine.

Comment: If you want GOTO, check this out: http://entrian.com/goto/ (it was an April Fools joke)

Answer (score 3):

`while choice is not 'q' or 'Q':` is parsed as

```
while (choice is not 'q') or 'Q':
```

so regardless of the value of `choice`, `Q` as a non-empty string will evaluate as true. Since you never change the value of `choice` in the loop, it will never terminate. You want something more like

```
choice = ''
while choice not in ['q', 'Q']:
    print "1) menu 1"
    print "2) menu 2"
    print "q) quit"

    choice = raw_input("?> ")
    if choice == "1":
        print "You chose 1"
    elif choice == "2":
        print "You chose 2"
```

---

Why you don't want to use `is not`:

```
>>> foo = 'Q'.lower()
>>> foo
'q'
>>> foo == 'q'
True
>>> foo is 'q'
False
```

As for the other suggested variations on determining whether `choice` is a upper- or lowercase 'q': pick whichever one you find most readable. Your program will spend vastly more time waiting for you to press a key than it will ever spend determining which key it was, so don't worry about which one is a split second faster than the others.

Comment: I may be wrong, but `while (choice is not 'q') and (choice is not 'Q')` would save a little space, no?

Comment: You'd probably want `while (choice != 'q') and (choice != 'Q')` anyway.

Comment: How about just `while choice.lower() != 'q'`...

Comment: +1, because this is almost a perfect answer. But it should also explain why `is not` is bad here. I don't know if can explain the difference between identity and equality to a novice in a couple of lines, but hopefully you can. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use an `else` clause to catch any invalid choices:

```
print "1) menu 1"
print "2) menu 2"

choice = raw_input("?> ")

if choice == 1:   
     print "menu1" 
elif choice == 2:
    print "menu2
else:
    print "Not a valid choice."
```

You can also use a while loop to keep repeating until a valid choice is made.

Comment: Change `else if` to `elif` and a colon after the `else`.  But yes, always remember to check for negatives

Comment: @Andenthal Thanks. Python isn't my primary language ;-)